# Programming a non-negative flow variable in python

Tags: python, gurobi

I am solving a facility problem in Python with Gurobi and one of the decision variable is a non-negative flow variable `g_ij > 0` to represent connections between facilities. That is, `g_ij > 0` if and only if `y_i = 1` and `y_j = 1` where `y_i = 1` if a facility is located at site `i` and `0` otherwise.

One of my constraint is `g_ij*(d_ij - k) >= 0`

where:

`g_ij` is the non-negative flow variable

`d_ij` is the distance in km between facilities `i` and `j`

`k` is `X`km

That is, the maximum allowable distance between facilities `i` and `j` is `X`km

I put the variable `g_ij` as a continuous variable with a lower bound `0` and upper bound `1`:

```
m = Model("flowTest")
n = 10
g = {}

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        g[(i,j)] = m.addVar(lb=0, ub=1, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="g%d%d" % (i,j))
```

and the constraint:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        m.addConstr(g[(i,j)] * (d[(i,j)] - k) >= 0)
```

but I get an infeasible solution. I am quite certain that it's because of the `g_ij` flow variable.

Anyone that can spot the error or suggest how I can program the `g_ij` variable?

Comment: It's not yet clear to me what your complete model looks like. Are `k` and `d_ij` constants? Can it happen that `d_ij` is smaller than `k`? In that case, the corresponding constraint is infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraint regarding the maximum distance is wrong:

If `d_ij` is the distance between facilities and `k` is your MAX allowed distance, then your constraint should be: 
`g_ij*(k - d_ij) >= 0` instead of `g_ij*(d_ij - k) >= 0`.

Otherwise the term `(d_ij - k)` will always be `<= 0` if `d_ij` is within `k`, wich means `g_ij` cant be positive.